# How to remotely downgrade apk on device?

Tags: java, android, apk

Might be a beginner question, i'm new to android studio.
I need to write a simple .apk on java which will load a react web-app.

If the new version of the app crashes, I'd like to downgrade the .apk. I assume by downloading the older version and installing it.

How could I structure the code the proper way to do that?
I'm not asking for the whole source code, just some tips of code structuring.

This ap is not for the market but for internal use.
So the OS version is fixed, 7.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share what you have tried.

Comment: You cannot downgrade. This is a security feature of Android. You can always only increase the versionCode. What you can do is get the old APK, increase the versionCode, re-sign it and re-publish it. An alternative is using increment rollouts through the Play Console and halt a rollout if you detect an issue. You still can't downgrade, but fewer users will be affected.

Comment: @amanb thanks for the welcome! Nothing yet. I'm gonna start writing the app tomorrow.

Comment: @Pierre thanks, but i meant the structure, like in React - you can wrap your app with a higher component which controls the version of the app and intercepts every error, registers telimetries etc... so you act depending on error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set the apk [version code](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning) correctly, most likely in your root build.gradle file.

If version code 1 is working and installed on your users devices, then apk with version code 2 is installed but crashes, you have two options:

1. Fix changes and submit to users as new apk version code 3 (they can
   update to this version)
2. Have user uninstall app, and re-install previous apk with version code 1.

Comment: veritas. Thanks for the answer. The thing is, i need to do it on my own if the user reports a bug. I don't want him to do anything cause (in my case) he shouldn't. It should be done remotely.

Comment: The user needs to install a new version, one way or another. You cannot remotely change the apk installed on a users device trivially (e.g rooted devices etc) AFAIK.